# Textmate code folding

Tags: javascript, textmate

I'm working on a big project so I use code folding a lot. I basically have two types of code:

1.

```
help.scroll = function() {
    // some code
}
```

2.

```
help.scroll = {
    // some code
};
```

So Textmate folds the first code, but doesn't folds the second one.

The original folding start marker looks like this

`foldingStartMarker = '^.*\bfunction\s*(\w+\s*)?\([^\)]*\)(\s*\{[^\}]*)?\s*$';`

I guess ending marker is ok as is

`foldingStopMarker = '^\s*\}';`

So my question is - How do I modify "foldingStartMarker" so that Textmate will fold both blocks of code.

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no idea about your textmate version, but the following may work as in textmate 2.0(9283):

```
{   foldingStartMarker = '\{\s*(//.*)?$|\[\s*(//.*)?$|\(\s*(//.*)?$';
    foldingStopMarker = '^\s*\}|^\s*\]|^\s*\)';
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked as I wanted! THX (my Textmate version is 1.5.10)